# Teradata create table from UNION of multi tables error: (3707)

Tags: sql, teradata

I am new to Teradata SQL. I am trying to write a query as below

```
Create table abc as
(
   with datasets as
   (
    select * from tableA
  UNION
    select * from tableB
)  );
```

I am getting an error:

> 3707

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you intend?

```
Create table abc as
  select * from tableA
UNION
  select * from tableB;
```

When you use a CTE, you should be referring to the CTE in a `FROM` clause.  However, no CTE is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I just ran the 2 sqls with union and works. But when I add create on top it still throws and error. the data load is huge, like 100,000000

Comment: create tabe failed(3707) syntax error expected something like a name or a unicode identifier or(between the AS keyword and the SELECT keyword

Comment: dnoeth, i just tried and your solution works. Sorry this seems very trivial but coming from sql server usage, I am finding Teradata sql somewhat different

Answer (score 2):

You should always show the exact error message, the syntax for `Create Table As` has a required parameter:

```
Create table abc as
 (
    select * from tableA
    UNION
    select * from tableB
 ) WITH DATA;
```

Do you really need `UNION`? `UNION ALL` will improve performance because it avoids the DISTINCT processing.

And don't forget to define the Primary Index, as CREATE TABLE AS SELECT will remove all indexes. Additionally all columns will be NULLable. To fix this it's better to create the table using

```
Create table abc as tableA WITH NO DATA; -- exact copy
```

followed by

```
insert into abc
select * from tableA
UNION
select * from tableB
```

Comment: And in case other folks don't know, if you don't explicitly declare your primary index column(s), Teradata just takes the first column in the table as the PI.  Which can result in your insert filling up an amp, or other fun stuff.